# New products not displaying on home page after product bulk upload

Tags: magento-1.9, product, static-block

I was trying to bulk upload products in magento before uploading products everything was normal but after uploading my New product block is not displaying on home page http://new.sporteemail.com

I have checked all these but its still not working

1. ***The products must be Visible in Catalog.***
2. ***The products must be Enabled.***
3. ***Product must have a stock Quantity.***
4. ***The product must be set to In Stock.***
5. ***The product must be assigned to the target Category.***

Comment: Try re-indexing first. If it doesn't solve issue, then read further. Which import method did you use, and can you share code for new product display ?

Comment: can you please check new product from date

Comment: May be store not assigned properly on prodcuts.

Comment: I used dataflow profiles to import all the products

Comment: while uploading products there was no new product from date but now i changed it manually but still its not working.

Comment: flushed cache? rebuilt index? has messages in system.log or exception.log? Is the product accessible via direct url?

Comment: Try to clear var/session and var/cache and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. -Did u try to save a product manually ? maybe u forgot something to import!
2. -Are the Categorys subcategorys of default?
3. -Cache / index refreshed?
4. -Try to disable the inventory in:

> system->configuration->Inventory->Product Stock Options and set
>       'Manage Stock' to 'No'

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-index after any import
2. Refresh all caches in `System --> Cache Management`
3. If you are using a CDN or full page caching you may need to flush those caches as well.